# How to call a function to renders items in a `ng-repeat` directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

I am writing a directive to output a list of items. Those items are meant to be read from a JSON somewhere.

Now, I want to render each item accordingly to a method that would be passed to the directive. Then, in my template, I call the method, passing it the item to be rendered.

The method itself is called, but the passed item is `undefined`.

Where am I wrong, and how to acheive this?

You can see and play with the code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/zpntqayr/

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.1/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <drop-down-list items="data" display-item="itemToString(item)" />
    </div>
    <script>

    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.data = [{ "Name": "Value 1", "Value": 1 }, { "Name": "Value 2", "Value": 2 }, { "Name": "Value 3", "Value": 3 }, ] ;
        $scope.itemToString = function (item) {
            // alert(item);
            return item.Name;
        };
    });

    myApp.directive('dropDownList', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                items: '=',
                displayItem: '&'
            },
            template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items">{{displayItem(item)}}</li></ul>',
        };
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the code in the directive template as below:

```
{{displayItem(item)}}
```

with

```
{{displayItem({item: item})}}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, it is working! Can you explain what is the difference between both syntax?